# How to avoid DLL not found error on T4 template?

Tags: c#, .net, templates, t4, assembly-loading

I created a T4 template to generate a partial class.

It references one of my DLLs:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)..\Base\bin\Debug\net8.0\Base.dll" #>
```

If the DLL doesn't exist, my template gives an error. I want it to run without errors.

If the DLL exist, I want to generate a class and implement it's methods.
If not, I want to generate the class with empty methods.

How to achieve this?

Comment: What, exactly, is in `Base.dll`? When you say "implement its methods", do you mean you want to reflect over an `interface` or `abstract class` containted within that assembly?

Comment: ....y'know, a better approach might be to use Roslyn Source Generators

Comment: Also, T4 runs within VS's AppDomain, which means it's stuck on .NET Framework 4.8, so you can't reliably load `net8.0` assemblies build-time-executed T4 (though obviously this doesn't apply to runtime-executed T4 templates)

Comment: @Dai I have an attribute defined in Base.dll.

I use that attribute to decide how to generate the partial method, based on the classes that have that attribute applied.

When I say "implement its methods" I mean to write code inside them

Comment: I think you should [use Roslyn for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) instead of T4 then.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `System.Reflection` and runtime assembly loading - using `<#@ assembly` configures a *compile-time* assembly reference for the implicit assembly generated from your T4 file, which obviously  won't work if the assembly doesn't exist.

> If the DLL doesn't exist, my template gives an error. I want it to run without errors.

I see you're using `$(ProjectDir)` which can be an MSBuild parameter, or passed as an environment-variable, or accesed via `this.Host` in T4, or by being strongly-coupled to VS via `EnvDTE` - so depending on how the T4 is being executed (T4 files normally run *within* Visual Studio, but they also need to run under `dotnet build` or `msbuidl` where `EnvDTE` isn't available. You need to figure out that requirement and choose the appropriate response.

But *other than that*, do something like this:

```
<#
    DirectoryInfo projectDir = GetProjectDirFromEnvSomehow( /* EnvDTE? this.Host? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "etc" ), etc etc */ );
    FileInfo baseDllFile = new FileInfo( Path.Combine( projectDir.FullName, "Base.dll" ) )

    if( baseDllFile.Exists )
    {
       // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context
#>
        public class Whatever
        {
<#
            foreach( var member in reflectedMembers ) { this.Write( "public TypeName MemberName { etc; }" ) }
#>
        }
<#

    }
    else
    {
#>
        public class Whatever {}
<#
    }

#>
```